# Joomla 3.2 modify com_content / category query / add a filter

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.2

I want to modify com_content / category to fit a custom database /w some additional fields (for compatibility-reasons with modified com_content from J1.5).

The function `_buildContentWhere`, that was available in Joomla 1.5 in **components/com_content/models/category.php** is gone.

I can't figure out, where I can modify the query to put an additional WHERE-clause now. I just want to list items in this category that fit a special condition (passed as GET-Param).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items are now retrieved querying another model, `com_content/models/articles`

The query is built in the `getListQuery()` method.

Comment: @ricardo-zorn YMMD! :-)